# Powershell - Unable to set the Company AD attribute

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm looking for some help as to why this is happening:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=x,OU=xx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com" -Properties *
```

Does not show the **"Company"** attribute for a computer. However, if I run:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=x,OU=xx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com" -Properties * | select name, company, location
```

The company attribute does show up. I'm trying to update the company attribute, but I assume it's not letting my because the attribute is not listed under **-properties***.

```
Set-ADComputer : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'company'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-Replace` (and `-Add`,`-Remove`,`-Clear`) parameters for attributes that don't have direct setter methods:

```
PS C:\> Get-ADComputer pc4711 |Set-ADComputer -Replace @{company='Evil Corp'}
PS C:\> Get-ADComputer pc4711 -Properties * |Select-Object name,company

name   company
----   -------
pc4711 Evil Corp
```

`-Replace` works both for objects with and without existing values. `-Add` would result in an error for objects with existing values, since the attribute `Company` can hold only a single value.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use this method to update the company attribute!

Comment: Can you reference in Microsoft documentation where it says you can use this?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider good catch .. +1 from me ...microsoft is confising at times.. anyway good one.  cheers.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adcomputer?view=win10-ps), the parameter `company` is not a valid parameter for computer accounts.

Comment: I can get behind that part, but why would I be able to see the company attribute by adding a " | select company" piece into the line when it wasn't originally listed with all the other properties? I was under the impression that what you could use a select statement for was limited to the items from your link.

Comment: What version of Windows Server are you using?

Comment: @powershell_help try adding anything instead of computer.. it will just echo with a blank result.. for example  Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase "OU=x,OU=xx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=com" -Properties * | select cat, dog, rat, company, location

Comment: by the way are you getting any result for select company ? i guess it's empty !

Comment: `Company` IS a [valid LDAP attribute for computer objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/c-computer). It's just that there aren't setter methods for all attributes, most have to be set different,

Comment: @GeraldSchneider if it’s a valid attribute, why isn’t it in the doco for Get-ADComputer or Set-ADComputer?

Comment: @Powershell_Help: `why would I be able to see the company attribute by adding a " | select company" piece into the line when it wasn't originally listed with all the other properties?` According to the documentation, Properties only returns a default set of properties, and Company obviously is not one of the default set.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adcomputer?view=win10-ps

Comment: @ChristopherH because the documentation of the cmdlet does not describe any attributes of the AD objects at all, it describes the methods of the cmdlet. Among the methods are the general modification methods I described in my answer. With these methods you can modify all (writable) attributes of the AD object, but you have to look up the available attributes in the documentation of the AD object, not the cmdlet.